# Convert a FUNCTION to a STRING or SYMBOL in Common Lisp

Tags: function, common-lisp, symbols

Is it possible in common lisp to convert a function to a symbol or a string for further use? What i mean is to get a `"+"` or `#:|+|` from `#'+`.

Comment: I'm wondering where this need comes from.

Comment: @zut In some other languages like Python, function objects have a name attribute, which could be useful some times (example would be implementing multimethods in Python using decorators). Maybe the OP is looking into something similar. Although OP could just wrap it in a cons cell of [function, name], it would be easier to know if CL has such a name attribute already, instead of having to wrap the function object in such an interface. Just guessing though.

Comment: @Byte In CL that would be the other way around. The function is a property of the symbol (the name) rather than the name being a property of the function. If you need both, you should use the symbol and access the function through it.

Comment: @jkiiski Agreed, but I don't think that holds true for function objects defined lexically with 'flet, or 'let with #'(lambda ...). If I remember the letoverlambda book correctly, the compiler does not create a symbol object when using 'let, so (symbol-function ...) would not make sense. The let binding is just a stack slot for a pointer to the function object I think.

Comment: True, functions defined with `FLET`/`LABELS`/`LAMBDA` aren't assigned to a symbol (automatically that is, you can of course assign them yourself). For debugging purposes at least on SBCL the `FUNCTION-LAMBDA-EXPRESSION` suggested in the answers seems to return a list `(FLET <name>)`/`(LABELS <name>)`/`(LAMBDA <lambda-list>)` for them, but those of course aren't actual function names (these are returned even if the functions are manually assigned to the symbol function slot of a symbol, which demonstrates the "not guaranteed to return anything useful" as sds said).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only *standard* way is
[`function-lambda-expression`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_fn_lam.htm)
which is *not* guaranteed to return anything useful.

Neverless, both CLISP and SBCL return the actual function name:

```
(nth-value 2 (function-lambda-expression #'+))
==> +
```

or, if you wish,

```
(symbol-name (nth-value 2 (function-lambda-expression #'+)))
==> "+"
```

Answer (score 5):

```
CL-USER> (nth-value 2 (function-lambda-expression #'sin))
SIN
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(defun function-name (fn)
  (string-downcase (symbol-name (nth-value 2 (function-lambda-expression fn)))))

(function-name #'atom) => "atom"
```